# return false is not working in javascript validation

Tags: javascript

```
function confirmValidation() {
    var confirmPass = document.getElementById('newpassword').value;
    var newpass = document.getElementById('newpassword2').value;
    var passLength = confirmPass.length;
    if ((confirmPass == newpass) && (confirmPass != "" && newpass != "") && (passLength > 8)) {
        alert("ok");
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("no");
        confirmPass.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

And input:

```
<input name="register" type="submit" class="alert_button" onclick="return confirmValidation()" value="OK" />
```

Comment: Please show your html code?

Comment: where are the other controls you are calling by Id in you JS

Comment: Why are most of the questions being downvoted off late on SO !

Comment: Which browser are  you using? I have heard Chrome had some issues earlier with onSubmit return. http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/Z3MD5Od3oQM

Answer (score 3):

For the `return` method to work, you need to specify `onSubmit` attribute/listener to the `form` tag itself. Like so:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return confirmValidation();">
    <!-- OTHER form fields -->
</form>
```

From [w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html) documentation:

> The `onsubmit` event occurs when a form is submitted. It only applies to the FORM element.

---

## EDIT

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/JMx2e/) added.

You must alter your JavaScript a little so that `.focus()` may fire.

```
function confirmValidation() {
    var confirmPass = document.getElementById('newpassword');
    var newpass = document.getElementById('newpassword2');
    var passLength = confirmPass.value.length;
    if ((confirmPass.value == newpass.value) && (confirmPass.value != "" && newpass.value != "") && (passLength > 8)) {
        alert("ok");
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("no");
        confirmPass.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: <form id="emailvalidate" name="emailvalidate" action="xyz.php" method="post" onsubmit="confirmValidation()">
 <div class="login_title">Create new password</div>
 <dl>
 <dt>New Password</dt>
 <dd><input name="newpassword" type="password" id="newpassword" size="40">
 <div class="register_alert">over 8 characters</div></dd>
 <dt>Confirm</dt>
 <dd><input name="newpassword2" type="password" id="newpassword2" size="40"></dd>
 <dt></dt>
 <dd><input name="register" type="submit" class="alert_button"  value="OK">
 <div class="login_alert">Password doesn't match.</div>
 </dd>
 </dl>
  
</form>

Comment: @user2122323 Edited reply. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

Move your validation to the form.

```
document.getElementById('my_form').addEventListener('submit', confirmValidation, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use onsubmit() event in  tag. Now when you submit the form, it will call the function that is written on the onsubmit() event. Only in case of Onsubmit(), it checks the return value if it's true then it proceeds further otherwise not.

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return confirmValidation();">

</form>
```